# PHP: How to prevent serialize from hitting a certain member

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have a User object whose protected member leads to a PDO object.

I'm using Silex/Symfony and when I try to login `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken` goes to serialize that object and gives an exception since PDO objects can't be serialized.

I tried making the member private but that didn't help. If I unset the property in __sleep I'm not sure how to put it back in __wakeup given that the member is set by being passed in the constructor.

The examples I've seen get back unserializable things via static lookups but I'm trying to avoid that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `Serializable` to your User Object.

```
class User implements UserInterface, Serializable
{
    // ...

    public function serialize()
    {
        // see http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        // see http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
        list ($this->id, $this->username, $this->password) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

**Warning**: This answer only to the question "*How to prevent serialize from hitting a certain member*". If you find yourself with a similar problem then you should rethink on what are you doing. See the answer of @Bryan Agee for more details.

Comment: For some reason if I do `return serialize($this);` from within the implemented `serialize` as a test, it doesn't explode even though the PDO bit is in there, and it just serializes to `string(4) "r:3;"`. I have to be missing something.

Comment: I edited with an example. However this allows you only to sweep the problem under the carpet. The problem lies elsewhere. See the answer of Bryan Agee

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your model object has persistence logic in it, which is the real root of your problem; you might want to take a look at the repository design pattern to get that sorted out.

In the mean time, the only real option for re-populating that PDO object is using evil globals; your __wakeup() would have to reach out and grab an isntance.

I suppose you could also override the service that loads the User and replace it with one that injects the database immediately after unserializing, but that seems a bit hairy--best just to extract the persistence code from the model and only serialize the model.

Comment: I have an object that makes queries and one that contains data. I am returning the object that contains data, but also has a reference to the manager of the objects so it can retrieve data from other entities. I might just swap that out to be better.

Comment: On that note, I'm going to upvote your answer but pick @Leggendario's as the answer since that technically answers the question and this answer helps out on my silly implementation details

Answer (score 0):

a small addition: JMS Serializer is a cool bundle ffor symfony that allows you to make annotations in your entity, selecting precisely which property/method you want to be serialized (or not).

check it out:
http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle#usage